# Expressions in a StackList

Tags: java

I am working on Postfix expressions. I have a stackList that will have ints pushed on as well as expressions (i.e. *,/,+,-). How do you pop the nodes evaluate the expression and pop the result back on? I understand how it is supposed to work but am having a hard time going from the concept to the code. Here is what I have for Multiplication. I know it does not compile. Once I understand one I am sure to understand the others. Thanks for the help.

```
 public class Expression 
{
private StackList yay;

public Object multiply()
{
    Object one = yay.pop();
    Object two = yay.pop();
    Object three= one * two;
    return yay.push(three);
}
}
```

Comment: The last line should be yay.push(three) ?

Comment: @miw yes I just caught that but I still get this error at object three=...
"The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object"

Comment: Since you are using Object to represent your values, you'll have to define your own version of multiplication. * is not a defined operator for Object. Instead, you could use int (auto-box to Integer) if that suits your requirements.

Comment: Is there an easy way to define my own multiplication?

Comment: Just replace Object by int, and it might just work, with auto-boxing magic...

Comment: I tried that but got a null pointer

Comment: Then something is wrong with code outside of the snippet that you gave in your question.

Comment: hmmm... my stacklist, linkedlist and listnode all work fine. It must be somthing else